# jq: find and replace within filter

Tags: jq

I return a few json values from an API feed using this command:

```
curl -s -u user:pass -H 'my header' https://example.com/data.json | jq -cr  '.[] | {id: .id, content: .content, assignee: .assignee.name}
```

I'm getting a CSV just as I need it, namely:

```
1235,"some text, sometimes with a comma, perhaps", "John Doe"
```

Everything is great, but command in the "content: .content" values are throwing off our processing of the data.

I'm trying to replace commas within the command, and not even sure what terminology to search for. Ideally I'd use something like this:

```
jq -cr  '.[] | {id: .id, content: *** BEGIN DO SOMETHING .content END DO SOMETHING***, assignee: .assignee.name}
```

...I just don't know what that *something* is.

I'm guessing it's a gsub, but not sure how to isolate the syntax for .content.

Answer (score 0):

Should waited the requisite 5 minutes.

Found my answer elsewhere:

```
jq -cr  '.[] | {id: .id, content: .content | sub(","; ""), assignee: .assignee.name}
```

Comment: Might want to use `gsub` to replace all commas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `gsub/2`.

Filter

```
. | gsub(",";"")
```

Input

```
1235,"some text, sometimes with a comma, perhaps", "John Doe"
```

Output

```
1235"some text sometimes with a comma perhaps" "John Doe"
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/n5fFtBK7uj